# Webscraping Beautifulsoup remove div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how do I remove the div brackets? I just want the names of the car models left: "E-Pace", "F-Pace SVR"...

Highly appreciate your input. I am new to coding so would be nice to get your solution.

Thank you

Code:

```
import requests
import time

#Inputs/URLs to scrape:
URL_model = ('https://carbuzz.com/cars/jaguar')
(response := requests.get(URL_model)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()

for car_model in soup.find_all(class_='sub-model-with-score-preview__name'):
    car_model
    print(car_model)
```

Output:

```
E-Pace        </div>
<div class="sub-model-with-score-preview__name">

F-Pace SVR        </div>
<div class="sub-model-with-score-preview__name">

F-Pace        </div>
<div class="sub-model-with-score-preview__name">

I-Pace        </div>
<div class="sub-model-with-score-preview__name">

F-Type Coupe        </div>
```

Comment: you can get value `.text` or use function`.get_text()`. To strip whitespaces `.text.strip()` or `.get_text(strip=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to extract the texts from your tag and use strip parameter to get rid of leasing/ trailing whitespaces or linebreaks:

```
print(car_model.get_text(strip=True)
```